# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined, js engine: hermes in react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import BackButtonHeader from "../../components/BackButtonHeader";
import { Text, Button } from "react-native-ui-lib";
import { View } from "react-native-ui-lib";
import {
  PlayerIcon,
  PauseIcon,
  CloseRecordIcon,
  RefreshRecordIcon,
} from "../../constants/Icons";
import { AudioRecorderPlayer, AudioUtils } from 'react-native-audio-recorder-player';

const audioRecorderPlayer = new AudioRecorderPlayer();

const SoundRecordScreen = () => {
  const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState(false);

  const onStartRecord = async () => {
    const path = AudioUtils.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/test.aac';
    const result = await audioRecorderPlayer.startRecorder(path);
    audioRecorderPlayer.addRecordBackListener((e) => {
      console.log(e.current_position);
    });
    console.log(result);
    setIsRecording(true);
  };

  const onStopRecord = async () => {
    const result = await audioRecorderPlayer.stopRecorder();
    audioRecorderPlayer.removeRecordBackListener();
    console.log(result);
    setIsRecording(false);
  };

  const textContent =
    "Try talking about what you want to\n get done this week.";

  return (
    <View className="bg-white h-screen">
      <View className="items-start">
        <BackButtonHeader />
      </View>
      <View className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center mt-20">
        <Text text60>Not sure what to say ?</Text>
        <Text className="mt-2 flex text-center">{textContent}</Text>
      </View>
      <View className='flex-1 justify-end mb-40'>
        <View className="flex justify-center items-center mt-20 space-y-8">
          <PauseIcon />
          <View className="flex flex-row justify-center items-center">
            <RefreshRecordIcon />
            <PlayerIcon />
            <CloseRecordIcon />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        {isRecording ? (
          <Button title="Stop Recording" onPress={onStopRecord} />
        ) : (
          <Button title="Start Recording" onPress={onStartRecord} />
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  ); 
};

export default SoundRecordScreen;
```

I tried a sound record app with use react native then add package which name react-native-audio-recorder-player and finally ,
I got this error in console => ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Why i got this error , i have installed neccesary npm package but anything not changed.